Blackmagic design cards on Linux
Which ones of the BlackMagic design cards do I need to run DaVinci Resolve normally on Linux ?
I need at the very least to have audio and video playback, and video encoding.
I don't plan to connect to any hardware for input or output.
This is just to make a video out of a series a pictures and some audio files.
